# Vuforia - Load DataSet from Internal Storage

Tags: android, load, dataset, metadata, vuforia

I use Quallcomm's Vuforia for Android to Image Recognition. I do download .dat and .xml files from a JSON webservice to internal storage that has a path like this;

```
 public void run() {
     File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               
        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AveaEtiket/"); 
                     if(dir.exists()==false) {
                          dir.mkdirs();
                             }
```

And i want to load these files from internal storage instead of files that exists in **assets folder** . Is there anyone familiar with this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuforia offers you different constants to specify the source to read the marker files from:

```
int markerDataFileStorageType;
markerDataFileStorageType = DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APP;
markerDataFileStorageType = DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE;
markerDataFileStorageType = DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE;
if (!dataSet.load(MARKER_FILE, markerDataFileStorageType)) {
...
```

Of course, for the absolute storage type, you need to provide the full file path.

Each storage type represents the following:

```
DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APP          -> INTERNAL or EXTERNAL storages
DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE  -> ASSETS
DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE     -> ABSOLUTE path
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information(+1), can i know what type of string should be given, if StorageType is STORAGE_APP ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The string should represent a relative path to the marker file on the specified storage. If you store the marker on the app storage's root folder (assets folder on Android for example), then just the name of the file should do the work. If you create a folder inside that storage type, then use it too in the file name/string.